# Set Event's cover offset_y via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My application creates events on Facebook, and uploads a photo that is used as the Cover photo for the Event. For example, this is the photo that I am using:

[image: Original Photo that is uploaded as cover]

However, the event's cover photo offset is not positioned how I would like it- it defaults to an offset of 0,0. This is how the photo will appear as the Event's Cover photo:

[image]

This cover photo is also used when you Share an event. It appears in your News Feed with the cover photo, which is cropped in the same horrible fashion:

[image]

In the Facebook Graph Explorer, I can GET the event (along with the "cover" field) and it shows me the following data:

```
"cover": {
"cover_id": 241493776007705, 
"source": "https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/1377242_241493776007705_886002404_n.jpg", 
"offset_y": 0, 
"offset_x": 0
```

}

Ideally, I would like the user to be able to manipulate the positioning of the Event's cover photo offsets from within my application, and then my application could set the Event's cover photo offsets so it displays correctly.

**Does anyone know if it possible to configure (during the event creation) or edit an Event's cover photo offsets using the Graph API?**

Thanks!